# How to avoid Mesh Distortion when Curves cutting themselves, especially with Subsurface Modifier?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, distort

I am failing on a embarrassing challenge. I am trying to create an actually pretty simple form, but I cant finish my work without distortion on my mesh.

[image]

This is the object I am working on.

So far I tried different strategies, but I have always the same issue:

[image]

As you can see, the Boolean modifier and all my other attempts failed.

The problem is the overlapping mesh obviously, but I don't know how to fix it.
My best attempt so far was to make the whole object from only 1 curve:

[image]

But then my Circle looks a not really symmetrically. And if you look closely enough you can still see a little shadow/distortion on the point where the curve hits herself.

Is there a common known workflow or something to help me finishing my project?

Comment: do you need to do it with a curve or can it be made with mesh?

Answer (score 1):

As you're talking about booleans it looks like you're open to do it with mesh (rather than only curve), so here is a solution:

- Create a torus (Major Segments: 24/Minor Segments: 8).
- Duplicate one of its circle, make it another object, extrude on the Z axis.
- Boolean the 2 objects.
- In *Top Ortho* view cut in half with the knife, then mirror the whole object.
- Use the knife to add some topology: <kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut orthogonally.
- Give your object a *Subsurf* and *Shade Smooth* to test the result.
- Use the same technic and also the *Spin* tool for the top of the object.

[image]

Comment: Thank you mate, this works fine. I still got some distortion in my mesh but it looks so much better than before :D

Comment: oh ok great I was not sure about where was your problem... yes I know it's not perfect, maybe with a higher subdivision (when you create your torus) you could have better result